# The number of values of $x$ where the function $f(x)=\cos x+\cos(\sqrt2x)$ attains its maximum is

Tags: calculus

> The number of values of $x$ where the function $f(x)=\cos x+\cos(\sqrt2x)$ attains its maximum is:
>   $(A)0$
>   $(B)1$
>   $(C)2$
>   $(D)\infty$

---

$$f'(x)=-\sin x-\sqrt2\sin(\sqrt2x)$$
Put $f'(x)=0$ to find the critical points.But i cannot find the critical points.

Comment: Do you mean global maximum or local maxima?  You weren't asked to find where the maxim(um)(a) (is)( are), just how many.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer should be 1.

First note that $f(x)$ can never be bigger than 2 as it is the sum of two functions who are always less than or equal to 1.

Next note $f(0) = 2$, hence $f(x)$ has a maximum value of 2.

Next note for $f(x) = 2$ we need $x = 2 \pi n$ and $\sqrt{2}x = 2 \pi m$, for some $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ ($n,m$ are integers). This only has 1 solution at $x = 0$. To see this say $x \neq 0$. Then $n,m \neq 0$. Now we substitute the first equation into the second to get $\sqrt{2}(2 \pi n) = 2 \pi m$ so $\sqrt{2}n =m$. Since $n,m \neq 0$ this would imply $\sqrt{2}$ is rational which is clearly a contradiction.

Comment: The OP asks about local maxima, as he/she says "critical points"
Furthermore the global maximum is 1, if it exists, 2 or infinite does not make sense

Comment: @Raffaele I believe the "critical points" analysis was an attempt to find the global maximum. Also, how many times does $\cos(x)$ reach its global maximum? What about $x^2(4-x^2)$? Furthermore, "its maximum" would mean the global maximum.

Comment: @Raffaele The OP said maximum not local maxima which I interpret to be global not local. Furthermore, the global maximum clearly isn't 1 as f(0) = 2 > 1.

Answer (score 0):

Use the formula
$$\cos (x)+\cos \left(\sqrt{2} x\right)=2 \cos \left(\frac{x}{2} \left(\sqrt{2} +1\right)\right) \cos \left(\frac{x}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{2} \right)\right)$$
to find that the given  function has infinite zeroes: the roots of the equations
$$\frac{x}{2} \left(1-\sqrt{2}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2}+k\,\pi;\;\frac{x}{2} \left(1+\sqrt{2}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2}+k\,\pi;\;k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
therefore by Rolle theorem it has infinite maxima and minima

Comment: What is x which give maximum?, for example